# How to install skype in fedora 17

Tags: linux, open-source

I want to install skype in fedora 17 I have tried this

```
//for dependences
yum install alsa-lib.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 \
glib2.i686 libSM.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXi.i686 \
libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXv.i686 libstdc++.i686 \
pulseaudio-libs.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686

//download a package from ths link
wget http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-static

//extract the package
mkdir /opt/skype
tar xvf skype_static* -C /opt/skype --strip-components=1

//Create libtiff.so.4 link
cd /usr/lib

ln -s libtiff.so.3 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.4

//Create Launcher, Link icons, lang and sounds
ln -s /opt/skype/skype.desktop /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/icons/skype.png
ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/pixmaps/skype.png

touch /usr/bin/skype
chmod 755 /usr/bin/skype

//add following content in /usr/bin/skype 
#!/bin/sh
export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"

$SKYPE_HOME/skype --resources=$SKYPE_HOME $*'
```

The installation was Okay but I cannot open the skype, can any one help me..

Comment: Also: "*but I cannot open the skype*" - How are you trying to open it? And in what way is that not working?

Comment: Running it says...?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to install a Beta version of Skype?  The current release is stable from what I have read, a new version actually was released, this would indicate a non-beta GA release.

Answer (score 1):

Get the [Skype 4.0.0.7 for Fedora RPM package](http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-fc10).

You can download the latest beta from the Skype Website, right click then click open with software install.

Answer (score 0):

This post may help you [install-skype-on-fedora-17](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-skype-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel-scientific-linux-sl/)

Answer (score 0):

To install Skype on Fedora follow this tutorial: [Install Skype on Fedora 17](http://www.abouthack.com/articles/linux/how-to-install-skype-on-fedora-17.html)

> #### Login as Root
>
> Most of the commands here requires root privileges, so log in as root.
>
> ```
> su
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sudo -i
> ```
>
> #### Download Skype
>
> You can either download uisng your web browser or via terminal its uo
>   tp you. But when you download using web browser you have download the
>   right version for your system.
>
> ```
> cd /home
> wget --trust-server-names http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-dynamic
> ```
>
> #### Extract and Install Skype
>
> ```
> mkdir /opt/skype
> tar xvf skype-4.1* -C /opt/skype --strip-components=1
> ```
>
> Create Launcher and Desktop Icons
>
> Running these commands will create Menu Launcher, Desktop Launcher and
>   fix Skype Icon.
>
> ```
> ln -s /opt/skype/skype.desktop /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
> ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/icons/skype.png
> ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/pixmaps/skype.png
>
>
> touch /usr/bin/skype
> chmod 755 /usr/bin/skype
> ```
>
> Open /usr/bin/skype/ and paste the following text.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"
> $SKYPE_HOME/skype --resources=$SKYPE_HOME $*
> ```
>
> #### Running Skype
>
> You can run skype via Terminal by using skype command. You can also
>   run Skype from the Applications Menu. Skype con be found on
>   Applications > internet > Skype

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 24, download skype from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/).

In my case it was version: `skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm`. Then, open terminal, go to `~/Downloads` and run:

```
[ecerquei@dev Downloads]$ sudo dnf install skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm
```

That is it!